# Sanctum with react SPA returning 419 page expired

Tags: php, reactjs, laravel, laravel-sanctum

I'm new to laravel and sanctum and after I followed the laravel doc for sanctum I get response 419 page expired.
[image]
I am using react for frontend and this is my fetch

```
 fetch("/sanctum/csrf-cookie", {
        credentials: "include"
    }).then(() => {
        let cookies = document.cookie.split("=");
        let token = cookies[1];
        fetch("api/login", {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": "true",
                credentials: "include",
                "X-CSRF-TOKEN": token
            },
            body: JSON.stringify(this.state)
        })
            .then(res => {
                status = res.status;
                return res.json();
            })
            .then(res => {
                if (status == 400) {
                    this.setState({ ...this.state, errors: res.body });
                    this.setAlerts();
                } else if (status == 401) {
                } else if (status == 201) {
                    this.props.history.push("/login");
                }
            });
    });
```

First I get the cookie and then I use this cookie to set it in the header.

For the backend I added the EnsureFrontEndRequestAreStateful class in the Kernel.php

```
  'api' => [
        'throttle:api',
        EnsureFrontendRequestsAreStateful::class,
        \Illuminate\Routing\Middleware\SubstituteBindings::class
    ],
```

This is my cors.php

```
    /*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) Configuration
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here you may configure your settings for cross-origin resource sharing
| or "CORS". This determines what cross-origin operations may execute
| in web browsers. You are free to adjust these settings as needed.
|
| To learn more: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS
|
*/

'paths' => ['api/*','sanctum/csrf-cookie'],

'allowed_methods' => ['*'],

'allowed_origins' => ['http://localhost:3000','http://127.0.0.1:8000'],

'allowed_origins_patterns' => [],

'allowed_headers' => ['*'],

'exposed_headers' => [],

'max_age' => 0,

'supports_credentials' => true,
```

in session.php I tried both this:

```php
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', 'localhost:3000, 127.0.0.1:8000'),
```

And this :

```
'domain' => env('SESSION_DOMAIN', null),
```

Response is still the same.
I tried to change the 'expiration' value in sanctum.php but to no avail.

My Api Route

```
Route::post('/login','App\Http\Controllers\UserController@login');
```

And my controller with the login function

```
public function login(UserLogin $request){
    $request->validated();
    $user = $this->userService->login($request);
    if($user === null){
        return response('There is no such combination of email and password', 422);
    }
    return response($user, 200);
}
```

I couldn't find or at least I couldn't recognise same problem as mine. I apologise in advance if this is dumb question or if it's already answered but I really couldn't find any similar problem out there.

**UPDATE:**
I forgot to add the request headers. Here there are:

```
 "headers": [
        {
            "name": "Accept",
            "value": "*/*"
        },
        {
            "name": "Accept-Encoding",
            "value": "gzip, deflate"
        },
        {
            "name": "Accept-Language",
            "value": "en-GB,en;q=0.5"
        },
        {
            "name": "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials",
            "value": "true"
        },
        {
            "name": "Connection",
            "value": "keep-alive"
        },
        {
            "name": "Content-Length",
            "value": "41"
        },
        {
            "name": "Content-Type",
            "value": "application/json"
        },
        {
            "name": "Cookie",
            "value": "XSRF-TOKEN=eyJpdiI6InFPQkdZYXQ0ZHAydHVWcDVISWZnVkE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiYldObmtKSmdYeVFmMUE5WnBoK044RVhJbVUyZXdpeWh2RXd1UGtYa2taSWVjL1lXKzNIdmVPLy9jWi9MbEJPN0pEOWxCbGNzTUs2NklEZFZMRHZNRDFndFRIM2JveUtoUklQalliSE9iQnhUS0hHLzk1dDlDYWt2aU94R1d2NXMiLCJtYWMiOiI4MzZlZmZkOGUxYTkzZDU2ZjZiNTdhM2FkMTA1N2VjZDg1NzU2MGM5M2IyYmI0NjJiYjEzYTg3OWUxOTY3NzcxIn0%3D; laravel_session=eyJpdiI6IjYzQkp2UjVnWEsyTklkclNUaERXd0E9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiemRSL3ZuVXltZXI0dksvWDJ2R282aG43MVo2c2RXK1hkRDNEZ05IK01BNFRzTWJ0ZmErd3lESUJIdUxVRWF4ZW04dlJRanh3SGNMQklSK3hHNFFvRDBmZkVSaVYya3lCWWJYK2FHeEdMY2lEb2Y0aDFqWmUxUkgrQ2YvWWNuQTMiLCJtYWMiOiJmNzRmMWFmNDJiNjFlNTRmNDJlMzljNGNmZjMxYzY3OGYxOTUwYTFmZDIyMDBiOWE5OTgwN2EzODMwNTBlOTIyIn0%3D"
        },
        {
            "name": "credentials",
            "value": "include"
        },
        {
            "name": "Host",
            "value": "127.0.0.1:8000"
        },
        {
            "name": "Origin",
            "value": "http://127.0.0.1:8000"
        },
        {
            "name": "Referer",
            "value": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/login"
        },
        {
            "name": "User-Agent",
            "value": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:84.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/84.0"
        },
        {
            "name": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
            "value": "eyJpdiI6InFPQkdZYXQ0ZHAydHVWcDVISWZnVkE9PSIsInZhbHVlIjoiYldObmtKSmdYeVFmMUE5WnBoK044RVhJbVUyZXdpeWh2RXd1UGtYa2taSWVjL1lXKzNIdmVPLy9jWi9MbEJPN0pEOWxCbGNzTUs2NklEZFZMRHZNRDFndFRIM2JveUtoUklQalliSE9iQnhUS0hHLzk1dDlDYWt2aU94R1d2NXMiLCJtYWMiOiI4MzZlZmZkOGUxYTkzZDU2ZjZiNTdhM2FkMTA1N2VjZDg1NzU2MGM5M2IyYmI0NjJiYjEzYTg3OWUxOTY3NzcxIn0%3D"
        }
    ]
```

**UPDATE:** Fixed the typo in the XSRF cookie

Comment: `document.cookie` is all document cookies separated by a `;` so you need to first split by `;` and then by `=` and then look for the correct cookie

Comment: Yes, that is if I have more than 1 cookie. However I have only 1 and for test purposes I did it like that. I will update the question with the request headers, I forgot to put them in the question. Thanks a lot!

Comment: use X-XSRF-TOKEN header instead of X-CSRF-TOKEN when sending the request since you are reading the `XSRF-TOKEN` from the cookie, you can read more about this in the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/csrf#csrf-x-xsrf-token)

Comment: @apokryfos Thanks a lot for that! I didn't noticed at all that I had a typo there. I fixed it in my code however it didn't help at all. Do you have any other Idea?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the following keys to your `.env`:

```
SESSION_DOMAIN=localhost
SANCTUM_STATEFUL_DOMAINS=localhost
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This did the trick. Can you please explain why is this set up in the .env file? I suppose that if we plan to publish our site in prod we have to change this which in order to do that we will need 2 env files One dev and one prod?
Once again thanks a lot for your response!

Comment: Yes you always need 2 .env files. This is an environment file so this file is different on every place/environment. For example your database credentials are in there so you can connect locally to your local db and in production with the production db.

Comment: Great, thanks a lot for the info. Appreciate it!